Can someone tell me if reading the phone state is possible now in 2024?
Can someone tell me if reading the phone state is possible now in 2024 because i had a broadcast listener in October 2023 that would listen to a call being performed and as soon as the call ended, it would send the call details like duration, call type to the server. But now when i am testing the same code, it is not working, the broadcast listener is not invoked after the call ends. i am testing it on android 13 device. I have attached the code for this listener. Your help is highly appreciated.
public class InfluencerCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "InfluencerCallListener";

    ArrayList<CallLogModel> callLog;
    private static CallLogListener callLogListener;

    CallLogModel callLogModel;
    InfluencerCallReceiver influencerCallReceiver;

    public interface InfluencerCallReceiver{
        void onItemClicked(String number, ArrayList<CallLogModel> log);
    }

    public InfluencerCallBroadcastReceiver(){

    }
    public InfluencerCallBroadcastReceiver(InfluencerCallReceiver influencerCallReceiver) {
        this.influencerCallReceiver = influencerCallReceiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d(TAG, "run: "+bundle);
        if (bundle.getString("incoming_number")!=null && Objects.equals(bundle.getString("state"), "IDLE")){
            String phoneNr = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getCallDetails(context,phoneNr);

                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    private void getCallDetails(Context context, String phone) {
        callLog = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("phondata", "getCallDetails: "+phone);

        String timestamp = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        Cursor managedCursor = context.getContentResolver().query ( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null,CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ? AND " + CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?" ,
                new String[]{phone}, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append( "Call Details :");
        Log.d("ShowDate", "getCallDetails: "+managedCursor.getCount());

        if ( managedCursor.moveToFirst() ) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
//            String phNumber = phone;
            String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
//            String callDate = String.valueOf(date1);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );

            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.parseLong(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
            switch( dircode ) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
            callLogModel = new CallLogModel();
            callLogModel.setPhoneNumber(phNumber);
            callLogModel.setCallType(dir);
            callLogModel.setCallDayTime(String.valueOf(callDayTime));
            callLogModel.setCallDuration(callDuration);

            callLog.add(callLogModel);

            managedCursor.close();
            sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phone +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No call log found for the number: " + phone);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getCallDetails: "+sb);

        if (influencerCallReceiver != null){
            influencerCallReceiver.onItemClicked(phone,callLog);
        }
    }

    //With this method you will get the timestamp of today at midnight
    public long getTodayTimestamp(){
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(new Date());

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return c2.getTimeInMillis();
    }

}

I checked if all the necessary permissions were granted, tested it on multiple devices, i tried logcat debugging the code to check if broadcast receiver was being hit but nothing worked. I initially thought this was happening because i created two different broadcast listeners to listen to the phone state, but then i deleted one of them. it still did not work.
Below is the code for manifest.
<receiver
            android:name=".CallListener"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>```


Not enough to declare in manifest since it is a dangerous permission. You need to promt the user to grant the permission. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

I have granted the runtime permission as well

It is totally working fine for me with TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED to track the phone states.
Make sure to take required run time permissions when the app gets created.
Mention this permission in Manifest :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

you will have to take run time permissions :
 // Check if the app has permission to read phone state
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted, request it
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted, proceed with your operations
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted
                // Proceed with your operations, such as registering the receiver
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
            }
        }
    }

PS: You may need to take more run time permissions as per requirements of your project.
